# How to dynamically set the name of a session variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to accomplish the following, but with a session variable (ie., 'session[:dynamically_named]'), rather than an instance variable. This is how I see it can be done with an instance variable:

```
instance_variable_set("@#{params[:key]}", params[:val])
```

Seeing how there doesn't seem to be a "session_variable_set", how can this be done, even with some alternative work around with a session variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set values on `session` like you would with an ordinary Hash, e.g.:

```
session[:dynamically_named] = 'some_value'

# or, to match your example code...

session[ params[:key] ] = params[:val]
```

Comment: I posted the exact same thing. There's no need for hacks. `session` already is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

`session` ( in a Rails controller) is a Hash, so use it like a Hash:

```
session[:foo] = 'bar'
```