# Rails session custom, dynamic name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to set key name for session?

```
@dynamic_value = 'dynamic_123'
session[@dynamic_value] = 1
```

Of course this doesn't work, but can I set session key in some way?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was answered here: [How to dynamically set the name of a session variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899447/how-to-dynamically-set-the-name-of-a-session-variable)

I think `session` is a normal hash (with indifferent access), the keys of which can be any string or symbol. That code that you posted should store `session['dynamic_123'] = 1` properly.

Comment: should but it doasn't. I also try change @dynamic.value = 'dynamic_123'.to_sym , but also doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Real late in chiming in here where you use an instance value, then stuff all you want in a hash

```
dynamic_value = @target.id
session["target_#{dynamic_value}"] = @target.id
```

or succinct:

```
session["target_#{@target.id}"] = @target.id
```

*double quotes necessary*